# How to fix "the method txpool_inspect does not exist/is not available"

Tags: ethereum, web3py, go-ethereum, ganache

I'm having trouble getting the python function `web3.geth.txpool.inspect()`  to work.

I've tried using a geth server from the command line, from the `ethereum/client-go` container, and from the `trufflesuite/ganache-cli:v6.7.0` container.

In every case, I get a txpool_inspect method missing error.  The code I'm running is very simple, using Python 3.7.5 or 3.8:

```
from web3 import Web3
thing = Web3("http://localhost:42424")
thing.geth.txpool.inspect()
```

I'm using web3py==5.2.2 .

For Geth I tried: `--dev --mine --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 42424 --verbosity 4`  I tried a variety of other start up options as well, nothing seems to get me past the subject identified error that txpool_inspect doesn't exist or is missing.

I'd like to get this working for test/dev environments first before trying it on a real blockchain.

Suggestions?

Comment: The error is being thrown by the web3 server - if I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Initiate Web3 with HTTPProvider:

   ```
   from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
   thing = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://localhost:42424"))
   thing.geth.txpool.inspect()
   ```
2. Run your node with rpcapi flag, for example:

   ```
   --http.api "eth,net,web3,txpool"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

@StillFantasy's answer is correct. I'm just updating to current `geth`'s version

as `--rpcapi` is deprecated use `--http.api` flag.

Like:

```
--http.api "eth,net,web3,txpool"
```